# Want to know what each word meaning in this command

Tags: java, command

I'm trying to run a node.js app on JVM with the help of avatar.js using the following command which I got into an article here:
http://blog.jonasbandi.net/2014/03/running-nodejs-applications-on-jvm-with.html

java -Djava.library.path=dist -jar dist/avatar-js.jar  app.js

Want to know what is the exact meaning of each and every word in this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented quite extensively on Oracle's website ( https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html ), as well as in the command itself (try `java -?` ).

The part `-Djava.library.path=dist` means:

```
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
```

So this sets the `java.library.path` property to `dist`. I think this may be relevant for using a JNI (Java Native Interface) extension, and it tells the JVM where to look for native library files.

The next part `-jar dist/avatar-js.jar app.js` instructs Java to execute the jar file named `dist/avatar-js.jar`, with `app.js` as program argument, which is document as follows:

```
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man java` (available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html) too) :

```
-Dproperty=value
```

Sets a system property value. The property variable is a string with no spaces that represents the name of the property. The value variable is a string that represents the value of the property. If value is a string with spaces, then enclose it in quotation marks (for example -Dfoo="foo bar").

```
-jar filename
```

Executes a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The filename argument is the name of a JAR file with a manifest that contains a line in the form Main-Class:classname that defines the class with the `public static void main(String[] args)` method that serves as your application's starting point.

When you use the -jar option, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored.
For more information about JAR files, see the following resources:

- [The Java Archive (JAR) Files guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/index.html)
- [Lesson : Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)